# HSQLDB QUERY correctness

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

**merge into TEST_TABLE a
            using (select ? ID1, ? ID2 from dual) b (ID1, ID2) on (a.ID2 = b.ID2)
when matched then
update SET a.ID1 = b.ID1
when not matched then
insert (a.ID1, a.ID2) values (b.ID1, b.ID2)**

Is the above HSQLDB query syntactically correct, to pass as a parameter to a JdbcTemplate object.update method ?

I have been getting too many errors and haven't been able to find any useful material online to help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not orrect at least for this reasons:

**select (? ID1 , ? ID2) b** has not type for the columns. Use **select (CAST(? AS INT) ID1 , CAST(? AS VARCHAR(10) ID2) b** with the intended type for these columns